# SwiftUI not updating UI after fetching data automatically from OpenWeather API

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, openweathermap

I'm facing an issue in my SwiftUI project where the UI is not updating automatically after fetching data. I have a WeatherViewModel fetching weather data for multiple locations, and the UI doesn't reflect the changes until I manually trigger an update by pressing a button. I've tried using @Published properties and ObservableObject, but the problem persists.

I attempted to use @Published properties and ObservableObject in my code.Despite these efforts, the UI still doesn't update automatically.

the weather data model:

```
import Foundation

import Foundation


// MARK: - Welcome
struct WeatherDataModel: Codable {
    let coord: Coord
    let weather: [Weather]
    let base: String
    let main: Main
    let visibility: Int
    let wind: Wind
    let clouds: Clouds
    let dt: Int
    let sys: Sys
    let timezone, id: Int
    let name: String
    let cod: Int
}

// MARK: - Clouds
struct Clouds: Codable {
    let all: Int
}

// MARK: - Coord
struct Coord: Codable {
    let lon, lat: Double
}

// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    let pressure, humidity: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case feelsLike = "feels_like"
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure, humidity
    }
}

// MARK: - Sys
struct Sys: Codable {
    let type, id: Int
    let country: String
    let sunrise, sunset: Int
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main, description, icon: String
}

// MARK: - Wind
struct Wind: Codable {
    let speed: Double
    let deg: Int
}

class Location: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String
    @Published  var weatherDataModel: WeatherDataModel?

    init(name: String) {
           self.name = name
       }

}

class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var locations: [Location] = []

    func fetchWeather(for location: Location) {
        // Implement API request to OpenWeatherMap using URLSession
        // You'll need to replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with your actual OpenWeatherMap API key
        let apiKey = "8281a792c5f995747b19a57c8e52ea8d"
        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(location.name)&appid=\(apiKey)"
//        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=mexico&appid=\(apiKey)"

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                return }

            do {
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDataModel.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    location.weatherDataModel = decodedData
                    print("Weather data fetched successfully: \(decodedData)")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding weather data: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
  





}
```

Also for some strange reason the view does update automatically with the .onAppear but then when I click the button which clearly has no code in it then the view updates and the data from the API is displayed.

the view receiving the data:

```
//
//  TestView.swift
//  Amun
//
//  Created by Richard Nkanga on 09/02/2024.
//

import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    @State var names = ["UNITED STATES", "Montreal", "Nigeria", "poland", "London"]
    @State private var newLocation = "Canada"
    @State private var isEditing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color(.background)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                    .onAppear {
                    }

                VStack {
                    List(viewModel.locations, id: \.id) { locs in

                        HStack {
                            Text(locs.name)
                            Text("\(Double(locs.weatherDataModel?.main.temp ?? 0))")

                            Spacer()

                            if let weatherData = locs.weatherDataModel {
                                Text("Temp: \(Int(weatherData.main.temp))°C")
                                Text("Temp: \(weatherData.name)")
                            } else {
                                Text("Loading...")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            
                    .onAppear {
                        for name in names {
                            let location = Location(name: name)
                            viewModel.locations.append(location)
                            viewModel.fetchWeather(for: location)
                        }
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        isEditing.toggle()



                    }, label: {
                        Text(isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)

                    })
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .navigationTitle("Weather")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    HomeView()
}
```

The ui never updates and just keeps showing loading...

Comment: Change Location to a struct

Comment: **Remove** your apikey from your post. Note, you maybe interested at the code I created in my github repo to do all this:  
https://github.com/workingDog/OWMCall

Answer (score 1):

Playing around a bit with your code the solution I came up with was to, first of all, switch to async/await, because the code would be shorter and more readable. I also found a Coding Key error: in the Sys struct the type and id need to be optional.

Here's how I modified your REST call to be async:

```
    func fetchWeather(for location: Location) async throws -> WeatherDataModel? {
        // Implement API request to OpenWeatherMap using URLSession
        // You'll need to replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with your actual OpenWeatherMap API key
        let apiKey = "******"
        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(location.name)&appid=\(apiKey)"
//        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=mexico&appid=\(apiKey)"

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return nil }
        
        /// Shortest async way
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDataModel.self, from: data)
            return decodedResponse
        } catch(let error) {
            print("Error decoding weather data: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
        
        /// Longest async version
        /*return await withCheckedContinuation { contination in
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                    return }

                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDataModel.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //location.weatherDataModel = decodedData
                        contination.resume(returning: decodedData)
                        print("Weather data fetched successfully: \(decodedData)")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding weather data: \(error)")
                }
            }.resume()
        }*/
    }
```

Then your Sys struct:

```
struct Sys: Codable {
    let type, id: Int?
    let country: String
    let sunrise, sunset: Int
}
```

As said in the comments, I also changed Location to be a struct:

```
struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var weatherDataModel: WeatherDataModel?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}
```

And, at the end change the onAppear with task modifier like so:

```
.task {
     for name in names {
         var location = Location(name: name)
         let weatherDataModel = try? await viewModel.fetchWeather(for: location)
         location.weatherDataModel = weatherDataModel
         /// IMPORTANT!!!  Append the location at the end.
         viewModel.locations.append(location)
      }
}
```

Here is important to use the append at the end of every operations, if you place it before your data won't be updated.
Let me know what do you think of this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Nesting classes conforming to `ObservableObject` cannot work. In practice the `Location` class is not needed at all because `WeatherDataModel` fortunately provides an `id` and `name` property.

This is a different `async` approach

- Import Foundation with `@preconcurrency` to suppress a `URLSession` warning

  ```
  @preconcurrency import Foundation
  ```
- Adopt `Identifiable` in `WeatherDataModel`

  ```
  struct WeatherDataModel: Decodable, Identifiable { …
  ```
- Declare `type` and `id` in `Sys` as optional

  ```
  let type, id: Int?
  ```
- Delete the CodingKeys in `Main` because the JSONDecoder manages the snake case keys
- Create an enum for different states

  ```
  enum LoadingState<Value> {
      case idle, loading, loaded(Value), failed(Error)
  }
  ```
- In `WeatherViewModel` publish the `state` and pass the names in `fetchWeather` which is marked as `async` and handles also the errors

  ```
  @MainActor
  class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var state: LoadingState<[WeatherDataModel]> = .idle

        private let apiKey = "••••••••••••••••••••"

        func fetchWeather(for names: [String]) async {
            state = .loading
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            var locations = [WeatherDataModel]()
            do {
                for name in names {
                    let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(name)&appid=\(apiKey)&units=metric"
                    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { throw URLError(.badURL) }
                    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                    let weather = try decoder.decode(WeatherDataModel.self, from: data)
                    locations.append(weather)
                }
                state = .loaded(locations)
            } catch {
                state = .failed(error)
            }
        }
  }
  ```
- In the view get the data asynchronously in a `.task` and `switch` on the published `state`

  ```
  struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    @State var names = ["UNITED STATES", "Montreal", "Nigeria", "Poland", "London"]
    @State private var newLocation = "Canada"
    @State private var isEditing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    switch viewModel.state {
                        case .idle: EmptyView()
                        case .loading: ProgressView()
                        case .loaded(let locations):
                            List(locations) { location in
                                HStack {
                                    let temperature: Measurement<UnitTemperature> = Measurement(value: location.main.temp, unit: .celsius)
                                    Text("Temp: " + temperature.description)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("Name: " + location.name)
                                }
                            }

                        case .failed(let error):
                            Text(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        isEditing.toggle()

                    }, label: {
                        Text(isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    })
                }
            }
            .task {
                await viewModel.fetchWeather(for: names)
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .navigationTitle("Weather")
        }
    }
  }
  ```

You could even decode `dt` in `WeatherDataModel` as well as `sunrise` and `sunset` in `Sys` as `Date` without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code in which the UI updates after fetching data from the OpenWeather API.

1. Changed "Location" to a struct.
2. Made properties in the "WeatherDataModel" optional to handle missing keys while decoding.
3. Added the completion handler in the "fetchWeather" function.

[image]

**Weather data model:**

```
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - WeatherDataModel
struct WeatherDataModel: Codable {
    let coord: Coord?
    let weather: [Weather]?
    let base: String?
    let main: Main?
    let visibility: Int?
    let wind: Wind?
    let clouds: Clouds?
    let dt: Int?
    let sys: Sys?
    let timezone, id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let cod: Int?
}

// MARK: - Clouds
struct Clouds: Codable {
    let all: Int?
}

// MARK: - Coord
struct Coord: Codable {
    let lon, lat: Double?
}

// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double?
    let pressure, humidity: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case feelsLike = "feels_like"
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure, humidity
    }
}

// MARK: - Sys
struct Sys: Codable {
    let type, id: Int?
    let country: String?
    let sunrise, sunset: Int?
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main, description, icon: String?
}

// MARK: - Wind
struct Wind: Codable {
    let speed: Double?
    let deg: Int?
}

// MARK: - Location
struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var weatherDataModel: WeatherDataModel?
}


// MARK: - WeatherViewModel
class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var locations: [Location] = []
    
    func fetchWeather(for location: Location, completion: @escaping (Location) -> Void) {
        let apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(location.name)&appid=\(apiKey)"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 401 {
                    print("Unauthorized: Check your API key")
                    // Handle unauthorized error here
                    return
                }
            }
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                var updatedLocation = location
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDataModel.self, from: data)
                print("Decoded data: \(decodedData)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    updatedLocation.weatherDataModel = decodedData
                    print("Weather data fetched successfully: \(decodedData)")
                    completion(updatedLocation)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding weather data: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**View receiving the data:**

```
// MARK: - HomeView
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    @State var names = ["UNITED STATES", "Montreal", "Nigeria", "Poland", "London"]
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(.white)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack {
                    List(viewModel.locations) { location in
                        HStack {
                            Text(location.name)
                            Spacer()
                            
                            if let weatherData = location.weatherDataModel {
                                Text("Temp: \(Int(weatherData.main?.temp ?? 0.0))°C")
                                Text("City: \(weatherData.name ?? "")")
                            } else {
                                Text("Loading...")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        isEditing.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text(isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    })
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .navigationTitle("Weather")
        }
        .onAppear {
            refreshWeatherData()
        }
    }
    
    private func refreshWeatherData() {
        for name in names {
            let location = Location(name: name)
            viewModel.fetchWeather(for: location) { updatedLocation in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    viewModel.locations.append(updatedLocation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - HomeView_Previews
#Preview {
    HomeView()
}
```